# Does it make sense to speak of a subalgebra that is not of the same type as their provenient algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let's say one departs from a algebra with a lot of structure, like a Banach algebra, or $C^*$-algebra or a von Neumann algebra; does it make sense to speak of a subalgebra of this original, in such a way that they are not, or cannot be seen as, the same type of algebra?

Like for example a subalgebra of a Banach algebra that is not a Banach algebra, or that cannot be seen as a Banach algebra by imposing the same norm as that of the provenient algebra?

Or a subalgebra of a von Neumann algebra that is not closed under the weak-operator topology and hence not a von Neumann algebra, but that is algebraically closed as to still be a algebra and not just a set.

I understand that for the majority of my examples, compatibility can be enforced by the overarching structure, that is, any subalgebra of a Banach algebra would also be a Banach algebra under the same norm, or any subalgebra of a von Neumann algebra would also be a von Neumann algebra by restricting the pre-dual of such a algebra on only those elements that are mapped into elements of the subalgebra, and hence this subalgebra has a pre-dual of its own.

My problem comes from trying to define a structure, in the spirit of category theory, that can be specialised for any type of a particular algebra by only requiring the minimal structure needed.
That is, if I consider a category $S[\mathscr{A}]$ in which all its elements are unital $*$-subalgebras from some unital $*$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$, in such a way that the units of the objects are the same as the unit of the bigger $*$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$.

Then if I were to put an arbitrary type of unital $*$-algebra into $S[\,\cdot\,]$, that has more structure than just being a $*$-algebra, can this strcture be irrevocabily lost on the objects? (So that $S$ kinda acts like a forgetfull functor). If that is so is there a specific name for a subalgebra that also preserves the additional structure?

Comment: Your question is very unclear (a) because "provenient" is not an English word, AFAIK, and (b) because it is unclear what you mean by "departs from an algebra with a lot of structure"|. Typically a Banach algebra will have many subalgebras that fail to be complete and hence fail to be Banach algebras (in fact, I suspect that is true for all infinite-dimensional Banach algebras).

Comment: I’m also not sure what exactly is your question, but perhaps the following two observations are useful: if $A$ is a $C^\ast$-algebra, $B$ is a $\ast$-algebra s.t. $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic as $\ast$-algebras, then there’s a unique norm on $B$ making it into a $C^\ast$-algebra, namely the norm induced by the norm of $A$ through the given isomorphism. In particular, if two $C^\ast$-algebras are isomorphic as $\ast$-algebras, then the isomorphism is isometric. The same holds for vNa’s. That is, if two vNa’s are isomorphic as $\ast$-algebras, then the isomorphism is isometric and binormal.

Comment: So in particular, the norm structure on a $C^\ast$-algebra or the normal structure on a vNa will not be lost if you apply the forgetful functor to the category of $\ast$-algebras with $\ast$-homomorphisms. In a similar spirit, because any isometric algebra homomorphism is automatically $\ast$-preserving for unital $C^\ast$-algebras, applying the forgetful functor to the category of normed algebras with contractive homomorphisms also remembers the $\ast$-structure on unital $C^\ast$-algebras and the normal structure on vNa’s.